# How do I wait to execute a command which starts a service that is dependent an another service's start?

Tags: windows, batch, batch-file

I need to write a batch script to run two services in Windows, let's call them S1 and S2. The start of S2 depends on the start of S1. I want to run S2 only after S1 starts listening on a particular port. How do I achieve this?

Comment: Use findstr together with netstat to look for the port.

Comment: please be more elaborative. How do I write this logic in batch file?

Comment: We are not here to teach you how to program cmd scripts.

Comment: [Findstr - Search for strings - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html), [Netstat - TCP/IP network connections - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/netstat.html)